# Does a operator norm exist to bound each element in sequence of bounded linear operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, contraction-operator

Assume we have a sequence, $(O_n)$, of bounded linear operators which map from $X$ to $X$ a finite dimensional Banach space. Also assume each operators has the same spectral radius, and $\rho(O_1)<1$.

Does an operator norm $\|\cdot\|$ exist such that $\|O_n\|<\alpha<1$ for all $n$. Just to clarify I want to know if a norm exists that does not depend on $n$.

I know that for a single operator, $O$, that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an operator norm $\|\cdot\|_{\epsilon}$, such that $\|O\|_{\epsilon}\le \rho(O)+\epsilon$. Now if $\rho(O)<1$. and since $\epsilon>0$ can be arbitrary we can pick an operator norm $\|\cdot\|_{\epsilon}$ such that a $\|O\|_{\epsilon}\le\alpha<1$.

I'm just not sure if you can construct the single operator norm such that $\|O_n\|<\alpha<1$ for all $n$.

Any advice or tips would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Did you mean *operator* norm ($\|AB\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$)?

Comment: I do mean a operator norm. I have updated the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Regardless of the operator norm chosen, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\|\begin{bmatrix}0&n\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left\|\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|=\infty.$

Comment: Makes sense. I has trying to use it to prove:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196675/composition-of-contractions-converge-to-the-null-operator

Any help there would be greatly appreciated.