# Composition of contractions converge to the null operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, contraction-operator

Assume we have a sequence, $(O_n)$, of bounded linear operators which map from $X$ to $X$ a finite dimensional Banach space. Also assume each operators has the same spectral radius, and $\rho(O_1)<1$.

Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}O_nO_{n-1}\cdots O_{1}=$ Null operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true in general. Take $O_{2k+1}=O_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $O_{2k}=O_1^T$.

If the operators were commuting *and* there were a uniform bound on the norms (for any fixed operator norm), I think it would be true.  Just commuting is not enough, as examples of the form $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&a_n\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$ show, with $0<|\lambda|<1$ and $|a_n|$ growing rapidly enough.  The above example shows having a uniform bound isn't enough.

Comment: What if $(O_n)$ was uniformly operator convergent to $O$?

Comment: By the second $O$ do you mean $0$?  If so then it would be easy to show that the limit is $0$ using $\|O_n A\|\leq \|O_n\|\|A\|$.

Comment: Hi, sorry $O$ was not the best symbol choice, I don't mean 0. I mean that it uniformly operator convergent to a bounded linear operator $O$

Comment: Also in this case I don't have commutativity.

Comment: Ah then to me it isn't immediately obvious but my guess is you can show it converges to zero in that case.

Comment: Oh, @tinyhippo, in that case couldn't you find an operator norm such that $\|O\|<1$, because $\rho(O)$ would be less than $1$? That would make it pretty easy to show then.

Comment: If for example $\rho(O)=\rho(O_1)$. Then that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an operator norm $\|\cdot\|_{\epsilon}$, such that $\|O\|_{\epsilon}\le \rho(O)+\epsilon$. Now if $\rho(O)=\rho(O_1)<1$. and since $\epsilon>0$ can be arbitrary we can pick an operator norm $\|\cdot\|_{\epsilon}$ such that a $\|O\|_{\epsilon}\le\alpha<1$.

But I'm still not sure how to proceed,

I'd guess
$\|O_n \cdots O_1\|_\epsilon\le \|O_n\|_{\epsilon}\cdots\|O_1\|_\epsilon$
which ideally i'd like to show is $\le$ than $\alpha^n\to0$.

But I'm not sure how to tie it together.

Comment: *If* you had that $\rho(O)<1$, I think you could have a norm with $\|O\|$ less than $1$, and then have $\|O_n\|\leq r<1$ eventually for some $r$, and then it would be straightforward.  But I realize I don't know why or if $\rho(O)$ is less than $1$. so I don't know.

Comment: @tinyhippo: I was having doubts because spectral radius isn't always lower semicontinuous, but we're on a finite dimensional space so the spectral radius is continuous.   So with renorming and having your hypotheses you can get an operator norm such that $\|O_n\|\leq r<1$ eventually, and then $\|O_NO_{N-1}\cdots O_nO_{n-1}\cdots O_1\|\leq r^{N-n}\|O_{n-1}\cdots O_1\|\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$.